# Python: How to project image pixels on to map using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, matplotlib

I am trying to take pixels from an image and plot them ontop of a Blue Marble map.  I have figured out how to project them on to the map.  I have just not been able to figure out how to color each individual pixel when they are projected onto the map.
I have been using the plot() method, when I do them individually the terminal automatically kills my process because it has to plot ~65000 times.  Is there another method I could use?  Is there a way to use an array of pixel colors in any of these methods?  Is this possible with PIL?

rgb is the color array with a 3-tuple ie. (14,0,0) etc.  full_x and full_y are a 2 dimensional array where it is # of pixels x 5 different x,y points (to make the pixel shape on the blue marble image)

This is where I tried to do an array of colors:

```
for i in range(len(rgb)):
    hexV = struct.pack('BBB',*rgb[i]).encode('hex')
    hexA.append('#' + hexV)

m.plot(full_x, full_y, color=hexA)
```

I have also tried:

```
for i in range(len(rgb)):
    hexV = struct.pack('BBB',*rgb[i]).encode('hex')
    #hexA.append('#' + hexV)
    hexA = '#' + hexV
    m.plot(full_x[i], full_y[i], color=hexA[i])
```

This is where I tried to do each pixel individually and then the process was automatically killed.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a runnable code example? it makes this a lot easier to debug.

Comment: There is a couple files that go along with it.  Is there a way to attach files on stack overflow?  Or is email the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who sees this and has the same problem:

Apparently all you have to use is scatter.  In order to map pixels/any other points with multiple colors use scatter with an x array, y array and pixel color array.